# Outer variable captured in Anonymous Methods (lambda)

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I just read MSDN and found something need any advise here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx

> A reference to the outer variable n is said to be **captured** when the delegate is created. Unlike local variables, the lifetime of a **captured** variable extends until the delegates that reference the anonymous methods are eligible for garbage collection.

Does the "Captured" means it will be copy by value?
But however I try to write a sample program as follow:

```
class Program
{

    class async_class
    {
        private int n = 0;

        public async_class()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Outer  n={0} address={1}", n, n.GetHashCode());
                System.Threading.Thread thread1 = new System.Threading.Thread( () =>
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Inner after n={0} address={1}", ++n, n.GetHashCode());
                });
                thread1.Start();
                //n = 10;
            }

        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        async_class class1 = new async_class();
     }
}
}
```

In this sample, the inner "++n" will write back to original outer "n". So the result will be.

> Outer n=0 address=0
>   Outer n=0 address=0
>   Inner after n=1 address=1
>   Outer n=1 address=1

Anyone could explain more detail about the **"captured"** outer variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the whole point of saying that it's captured is that it's *not* just copying the values.  Closures close over *variables*, not over *values*.  Every single access of `n` in your program is accessing the same variable, there are never any copies made of it.

That said, your program is a confusing example of this case; it is using multiple threads, and that is introducing all sorts of race conditions as you are not safely manipulating the variable from multiple threads.  This will cause all sorts of undefined behaviors.  If you want to study closures, do so from a single thread; it will make your program much, much, *much* easier to reason about.

You can write *much* simpler programs to demonstrate that closures close over variables, not values.  Here's a simple snippet:

```
int n = 2;
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(n);
n = 5;
a();
```

If the closure captured the value of `n`, this would print 2.  If it closes over the *variable* instead of its *value*, it will print 5.  Go ahead and run it to see what happens.